# Select first purchase for each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are trying to select the first purchase for each customer in a table similar to this:

```
transaction_no  customer_id  operator_id  purchase_date
20503           1            5            2012-08-24
20504           1            7            2013-10-15
20505           2            5            2013-09-05
20506           3            7            2010-09-06
20507           3            7            2012-07-30
```

The expected result from the query that we are trying to achieve is:

```
transaction_no  customer_id  operator_id  first_occurence
20503           1            5            2012-08-24
20505           2            5            2013-09-05
20506           3            7            2010-09-06
```

The closest we've got is the following query:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) As first_occurence
FROM Sales_Transactions_Header
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

With the following result:

```
customer_id  first_occurence
1            2012-08-24
2            2013-09-05
3            2010-09-06
```

But when we select the rest of the needed fields we obviously have to add them to the GROUP BY clause which will make the result from MIN different. We have also tried to joining it on itself, but haven't made any progress.

How do we get the rest of the correlated values without making the aggregate function confused?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply treat the query you have come up with as an inner query. This will work on older version of SQL Server as well (you didn't specify version of SQL Server).

```
SELECT H.transaction_no, H.customer_id, H.operator_id, H.purchase_date
FROM Sales_Transactions_Header H
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT customer_id, MIN(purchase_date) As first_occurence
    FROM Sales_Transactions_Header
    GROUP BY customer_id) X
ON H.customer_id = X.customer_id AND H.purchase_date = X.first_occurence
```

Comment: This works perfectly after changing H.* to H.transaction_no, H.customer_id, H.operator_id, H.purchase_date as there is loads of other columns in the table.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to help you with that.

This is how to do it for your case.

```
WITH Occurences AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id order by purchase_date ) AS "Occurence"            
    FROM Sales_Transactions_Header
)
SELECT 
    transaction_no,
    customer_id,
    operator_id,
    purchase_date
FROM Occurences 
WHERE Occurence = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for a CTE!

[Clicky!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffa82/7)

The CTE will allow you to get the earliest purchase date for each customer.  Then you join that back to your original table on customer_id and the date, getting the rest of the information for that transaction.

Like so:

```
with first_date as(
  select customer_id,
  min(purchase_date) as first_purchase
  from
  table1
  group by
  customer_id
)
select
t1.transaction_no,
t1.customer_id,
t1.operator_id,
t1.purchase_date
from
table1 t1
inner join first_date
on
purchase_date = first_purchase
and t1.customer_id = first_date.customer_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Below query will also provide the solution

```
select * from customer_sale_details 
     where purchase_date in (select min(purchase_date)
           from customer_sale_details c1 group by c1.customer_id);
```

Comment: This could actually return wrong values if the min purchase_date matches a different purchase_date from another customer_sale_details